# From within a Controller's action, how can I get the current route information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

From within a Controller's action, how can I get the current route information?

How can I loop through the other routes?

Answer (score 3):

`RouteData` is a key/value collection:

```
this.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

..will return the controller of the current route.

```
this.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

..will return the action, etc..